# What is the best way to generate an svn compatible diff when using git svn?

Tags: git, svn, diff

I'm using git to track the [wireshark project](http://www.wireshark.org/). I'd like to submit a patch, however the format required is the output of the following (see http://www.wireshark.org/develop.html):

```
svn diff > my-new-protocol.patch
```

Which is a different format what `git-diff` produces.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

There is a helper script to do this: https://gist.github.com/44537